# how to design a booking system for online/offline use?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, web-applications

I need to develop a hotel booking system which will be used for in house bookings(for walk in customers) and online on the website.  What shall be the best approach

a) Have two applications(online/offline) & databases and synchronizing them at intervals
b) Have one web application and one database on the web server

what will be pros and cons of the two approaches?

I will be using c#/sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An obvious disadvantage I can see to the first option would be that if you are synchronizing the applications intermittently, you may end up with a situation in which you double book a room. So due to this I couldn't really recommend the first approach given the situation you describe.

The flip side of this argument is that with a single web application you don't have the issue relating to accidental double bookings.

Answer (score 0):

Why to have two applications? For walkin customers also, your executives can use same web application and database, it will avoid double bookings.